# Querying the Firebase Firestore and ordering it causes an error

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am doing a simple query to get the data I need from the firestore.

```
this.unsubscribe = this.ref
  .where('channelId', '==', `${currentChannel.id}`)
  .orderBy('createdAt', 'asc')
  .onSnapshot(this.onCollectionUpdate);
```

Ref is just a reference to my collection.

When I have either the `.where` or the `.orderBy` it works fine but when I chain them together which is something that according to the docs as seen here https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data?authuser=0 you can do it but in my case it throws an error:

`SnapshotError: Firestore: Operation was rejected because the system is not in a state required for the operation's execution`

Any help will be much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Do you have an index on `channelId` and `createdAt`? The error suggests that there is one, but it's not ready yet.

Comment: A long shot here, can you try building the index in you web console

Comment: @SamiHult I am using React Native Firebase. I am not working on a web project. So in their docs they were saying that I had to click a url which I am not seeing. But I created the indexes manually and still nothing happens.

Comment: @cutiko I did try this already.

Comment: @pap And you are certain that the indexing has completed already? This can be seen in the web console. If it's ready to go, you could try removing the index and building it again. I've sometimes had surprising issues with indices.

Comment: @SamiHult Yeah its done. At least what it says in the console.

Comment: Made a quick google searchn and I would like to insist on the index https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/453

Comment: @cutiko I have added an image to the description of the issue showing taht these two fields have enabled indexing. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After waiting for almost 25 mins it magically sorted itself out.

For people reading this please be patient in case you get this error and the console says that everything has been enabled. It takes much more time.